# Different -Wsign-conversion behavior when creating array with member

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm seeing different sign conversion warning behavior when I allocate an array with a member variable as the size than when I allocate with a non-member variable.

If I create an array with a member variable of type `const int` I get a `warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘const int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]` warning. I get this warning even if I `static_cast` the member to `long unsigned int`. If I initialize the array with a non-member variable of type `const int` I get no sign conversion warnings.

I'm seeing this with gcc 7.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04, compiling with just `g++ -Wsign-conversion main.cpp`

Example:

```
const int sz = 1;

class Foo
{
  Foo()
    :
      m_arr1(new char[sz]),                                       // no warning
      m_arr2(new char[static_cast<long unsigned int>(sz)]),       // no warning
      m_arr3(new char[m_arr_sz]),                                 // warning
      m_arr4(new char[static_cast<long unsigned int>(m_arr_sz)])  // warning
  {

  }

  ~Foo()
  {
    delete[] m_arr1;
    delete[] m_arr2;
    delete[] m_arr3;
    delete[] m_arr4;
  }

private:
  const int m_arr_sz = 1;
  char* m_arr1;
  char* m_arr2;
  char* m_arr3;
  char* m_arr4;
};


int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

It doesn't seem to matter whether the initialization happens in the member initializer list, or in the body of the constructor, or if the array being initialized is a member or not.

Is this a bug? Or is there actually some difference that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have `const int sz = 1;` in the global scope it is a constant expression.  This means the compiler knows 100% what the value is and it knows that since the value of `sz` is represetanble in the range of an unsigned integer type it does not issue a warning.

Conversely, `const int m_arr_sz = 1;` in the class is not a constant expression.  It is a member of the class, and it will be initialized to `1` if no initializer is given in a constructor.  This makes the variable a "run time variable", i.e. one whose value might not be known at compile time.  Since that is the case, gcc is going to issue a warning since it can't guarantee in all cases that you'll get the correct behavior.  Yes, in this trivial case it could do a more in-depth static analysis, but that slows down compile times.  It's easier to just issue a warning.

Comment: That makes sense, but then why does explicitly casting `m_arr_sz` to `long unsigned int` not suppress the warning?

Comment: @shay Because casting it could still give you the same behavior.  No matter how you do it if variable holds `-1` then the result is going to be a very large number.  The cast won't stop that behavior so you still get a warning.